# How to save user data when updating AIR mobile app (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, mobile, air

I save all user data in the SQLite database. These data include settings, a content, purchased items, etc. However, when user update the app (on market), all these *.db files are overwritten and the data is lost. How to avoid it?

I use this code:

```
var embededSessionDB:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(strPath);
var writeSessionDB:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(strPath);
if (!writeSessionDB.exists) {
    embededSessionDB.copyTo(writeSessionDB);
}
conn = new SQLConnection();
conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);
conn.openAsync(writeSessionDB);
```